# How to upgrade TIY into T&T Emporium in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How can you upgrade TIY into T&T Emporium in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AC:NL wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/T%26T_Emporium):

> To upgrade to T&T Emporium, the player must spend at least 100,000 Bells at T.I.Y., complete four Gracie Fashion Checks and have had the store open for at least 30 days. Gracie doesn't appear at your town Plaza until you have spent 70,000 bells at T.I.Y.

So you're looking at a pretty involved process to get it.  You need to spend at least 170,000 bells, total, and that's going to take some time to accumulate.  Which makes sense, as its the last upgrade for the shop.

Answer (score -1):

According to Animal crossing wiki:

> To upgrade to T.I.Y., the player must spend a total of 50,000 Bells in
>   Super T&T and 21 days have passed since the opening of the store.
>
> To upgrade to T&T Emporium, the player must spend 100,000 Bells,
>   complete four Gracie Fashion Checks and have had the store open for 30
>   days before the option to upgrade is made available.

You have to spend alot of money at the store and complete Grace fashion checks to upgrade it!

Hope this helps ｡◕ ‿ ◕｡